# How can I use VectorDrawable with the Android Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-vectordrawable

What is the proper method to use the new VectorDrawable in the toolbar?

I tried to use the `app:srcCompat` element as illustrated below, but nothing showed up.

```
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

I have my own toolbar layout using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and Android Support Library v23.2 on JB (16).

Comment: you could try MenuItem.setIcon() at runtime

Comment: @vigilancer your comment put me on the right track and it works. Make a real answer with a small snippet and I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Turns out it's quite easy.
Say, you have vector drawable `vd_trash_24dp`.

Describing MenuItem one cannot address VectorDrawable directly with `android:icon`. It seems ignoring `app:srcCompat` also.

But. As [all we know](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) ;)

> AppCompat does support loading vector drawables when they are
>   referenced in another drawable container such as a StateListDrawable,
>   InsetDrawable, LayerDrawable, LevelListDrawable, and RotateDrawable

Let's try it, should we?

Create StateListDrawable `vd_test_vd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/vd_trash_24dp" />

</selector>
```

than

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_action_filter"
          android:title="@string/menu_action_filter"
          android:icon="@drawable/vd_test_vd"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

street magic indeed.

Yes, one could try and set drawable at runtime with `MenuItem.setIcon()`. But who need that %)

Comment: > As of Android Support Library 23.3.0, support vector drawables can only be loaded via app:srcCompat or setImageResource().. It looks like in version 23.3.0 of the Support Library, you can only load VectorDrawables via app:srcCompat and setImageResource. [Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Comment: app keeps crashing on support library 24.1.1

Comment: this seems to be working now (verified in 24.2.1) without the `StateListDrawable` fyi

Comment: Thanks! That came very handy!

Comment: Another method is to use the drawable you get from AppCompatResources.getDrawable

Comment: Nicely done! You remind me one of my friend who used to clip things!

Comment: DiscDev, you must be new to all this :) That's just one of the many.